# Using Regex in String.matches in java to match a date format

Tags: java, regex, string, date-format, simpledateformat

**Validating the given date against the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Valid = 1 

Not Valid = -1** 

    Example1:
    Input= 12/06/1987
    output=1
    Example2:
    Input= 03/1/1987
    output=-1

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class CheckDateFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="29/02/2006";
        getvalues(s1);
    }
    public static void getvalues(String s1) {
        if(s1.matches("[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}"))
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            try {
                Date d1=sdf.parse(s1);
                System.out.println(1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();//Always going to catch block
                System.out.println(-1);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```

The problem with the code is that it it always returns -1. 
It always enters the catch block and gives a ParseException.
 
Is there any problem with the Regex?

Comment: you should do your homework by yourself.
search for online regex testers and try it there

Comment: You're also confusing "returning" and "printing". You should also inform your teacher that Java has a boolean type, that should be used here instead of 1/-1. And it enter the catch block because there are only 28 days in february 2006. So the date 29/02/2006 is invalid.

Comment: Are you trying to validate date or just validate the format? If you are validating date strictly the exception you got was correct ,since 29/02/2006 is invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

and this date:

```
String s1="29/02/2006";
```

As `2006` **wasn't a leap year** making your date invalid and with **lenient** set to false date parse call is failing and throwing `ParseException`.

Problem will be fixed if you comment out `sdf.setLenient(false);` line:

or use a valid date:

```
String s1="29/02/2008";
```

Since `2008` was a leap year making 29th Feb a valid date.

Comment: Yes it did work. Problem was with leap year date. Got to learn through my mistake. Thank you

Comment: Sorry friend I still don't have 15 reputation so can't vote.
Will mark it as soon as i can. Thank you once again

Comment: No you don't need 15 reps to accept an answer. Click on the link I provided in comment above to see how to accept an answer. You just need to click the tick mark on top-left of my answer and it will turn green. You will also get 2 points for that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regex. If you get a `ParseException` you can `return -1` else you `return 1`:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class CheckDateFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="29/02/2006";
        System.out.println(getvalues(s1));
    }
    public static int getvalues(String s1) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date d1=sdf.parse(s1);
            System.out.println(1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is thrown due to following line. Comment it off.

sdf.setLenient(false);

Answer (score 0):

As the year 2006 was not leap year, using `String s1="29/02/2006";` will throw a parse exception.

Try with other dates it will work fine.